# Why this question is still open and not migrated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why this question "[Windows utility to render which key I am pressing on-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/104421/windows-utility-to-render-which-key-i-am-pressing-on-screen)" is still open and not tagged as *"software recommendations"*  and migrated to [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions older than 60 days simply **cannot** be migrated, migration for these questions [is disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Other than that we don't go hunting for old questions to close because it would be a long and nearly fruitless task. I'll close a question like this if I happen to see it but I, and other moderators and high rep users, will not spend time ferreting them out.  There's other more productive things to do with our time.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the age thing. TIL.

Comment: I'll try to find a canonical meta.stack question regarding it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It wouldn't be a criticism, just a question. I didn't know about the time limit too, so I didn't know the action to do.

Comment: Theres a blog post at least which states *"Finally, be extremely reluctant to migrate old, answered questions. The votes and answers on these reflect the opinions and work of the community where they originated, and in most cases they'll be somewhat out of place elsewhere"* http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/ I guess that was made policy.

Comment: @Mokubai  __"Only migrate these questions when the alternative is deletion."__ I understand and like the position. Thanks for the ulterior _blog digging_ `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's 5 years old and nobody noticed. It also has no flags (that I can see). SoftwareRecs.SE has only been around for a short time as well.

Comment: Thanks 4 answer. I was asking because there are, seldom, exceptions for old and/or high rated questions...  (more work  for the administrators  to migrate them respect a new question...)

Comment: It's possible that's the case. However, questions like that are normally locked or protected if they are an exception.

Comment: Let's we see what they will do... I just put the spot.